# An error during boot that I can not see

Tags: fedora, boot, logs, kernel-modules

When I boot fedora, It shows an failure about modules and it disappears and then splash appears. I checked the `/var/log/boot.log` but there was no errors or failures there.

Where can I find it?

Comment: `dmesg | less`, /var/log/messages, journalctl

Comment: @JodkaLemon i don't have **/var/log/messages, journalctl** and
**dmesg | less** is veeeery long. how can i search in it?

Comment: `journalctl` and `dmesg|less` are two separate commands. You can pipe them to `grep` to show only matching lines. No `journalctl`?

Comment: I found something:

dmesg|less|grep fail
[    1.043603] systemd[1]: Unit systemd-modules-load.service entered failed state.
[    1.043626] systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service failed.
[    5.284838] vboxdrv: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel

Comment: Matin, just a general know how, if you pipe an output you either pipe it to `less` and do a search from within there or pipe it to `grep` and use that to search, not both. From within `less` you can press `/` to do a search.

Answer (score 2):

Since Fedora 20 there is `journalctl`. You can do

```
journalctl -b -p err
```

to print the logs from last **b**oot with **p**riority **err**or.

There are the following priorities for the logs: “emerg”, “alert”, “crit”, “err”, “warning”, “notice”, “info”, “debug”.

You can also just print the whole boot log and search in it:

```
journalctl -b
```

List the last boots:

```
journalctl --list-boots
```

and select one, that you want to read (-1 is the one prior to the current boot):

```
journalctl --boot=-1
```